# using file upload control to upload a file and pass the file to an object/web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, webforms, tfs-sdk

I would like to attach a file on a web page and save it in TFS.

I am using the asp.net fileupload control to save the file . 
            Can anyone please tell me how I can insert the accessed file from fileupload
            control into tfs ?

Here is my code :

```
   protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
   {
       FileUpload fu = (FileUpload)FormView1.FindControl("FileUpLoad1");

        if (fu.HasFile)
        {

       // I want to know the code changes to the line below :               
        workitem.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("file accessed from file upload", "comment"));
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me in aspx.vb world :o)
Rgds,
Mav.

```
 Dim objFSO, objFolder
 objFolder = "D:\dump\"
 objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 objFSO.CreateFolder(objFolder)
 System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(objFolder.ToString)
 Dim physicalFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString
 Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName)
 Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName)
 FileUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder, _ 
  fileName + extension))
```

Comment: are you saving the file to your D drive here ? I would like to pass the file accessed from the fileupload control and send the file to an object

Comment: You will have to save the file locally first and thenpass it to TFS.

Comment: I am using a web application which I will deploy to a server. So you mean save it on the server and then access the file from the server ?